# Python traceback Exception stack serialize as dictionary or list

Tags: python, python-3.x, traceback

How to get the exception stack `traceback.format_exc()` as a List/Dictionary in order to then serialize it with json.dumps()?

Comment: Could you please add more details? It's not clear (to me at least) what you're after.

Comment: @CristiFati I'd like to encode the full stack as JSON.

Comment: Yes, but how? Do you have an example?

Comment: @CristiFati Nope, not been able to find a way to get it as a dict or a list...

Comment: This will return a list, ```traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: traceback - Print or retrieve a stack traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#module-traceback).

If my understanding is correct, you're after something like this:

> ```py
> >>> import os, traceback
> >>>
> >>> try: os.open()
> ... except: tb = traceback.format_exc()
> ... else: tb = None
> ...
> >>> print(type(tb), tb)
> <class 'str'> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: open() missing required argument 'path' (pos 1)
>
> >>> [i for i in x.split("\n") if i]
> ['Traceback (most recent call last):', '  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>', "NameError: name 'os' is not defined"]
> ```

Once you have the exception traceback string, you can now manipulate it in any way you wish.